# Problemas para obtener mi hora actual de mi zona horaria

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Lo que trato de realizar es insertar la fecha junto con la hora lo intente de una forma y me funciona pero el problema es la hora que me esta insertando una hora que no es la correcta

Aqui es donde trato de obtener la fecha y hora pero tengo problemas con la hora intente de esta forma y me funciona pero la hora no me inserta correctamente   $ahora= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

```
  public function model(array $row)
    {

        $date =  strtotime($row['PERIODO']);
        $dat= date("Ymd H:i:s", $date);


        $hoy = date("Y-m-d");
//        $ahora= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $moneda='D';

        $tc_factura=25;

        date_default_timezone_set("America/tegucigalpa"); // ("America/Santiago") por ejemplo
        $timestamp = time();
        $ahora = getdate($timestamp);

        return new importar([
            "PROVEEDOR"=> $row['PROVEEDOR'],
            "DESC_ENLACE" => $row['DESC_ENLACE'],
            "NO_FACTURA" => $row['NO_FACTURA'],
            "ID_ENLACE" => $row['ID_ENLACE'],
            "VALOR_PAGO" => $row['VALOR_PAGO'],
            "PERIODO" => $dat,
            "FECHA_FACTURA" => $hoy,
            "FECHA_INGRESO" => $ahora,
            "MONEDA" => $moneda,
            'TC_FACTURA' => $tc_factura,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El Laravel la configuración de tu zona horaria va en:

- Ingresa a tu carpeta raíz
- Ve a la carpeta *config*
- Ve al archivo *app.php*

Dentro de este existe un vector asociativo de valores, busca la clave `timezone`

Una vez ubicada sustituye el valor por defecto que es `UTC` por tu zona horaria y con eso debería bastar

Sin contar que para recuperar los datos que quieres no hace falta hacerlo así, ya que la clase *Carbon* tiene en Laravel un helper llamado `now| así como métodos que simplifican esto, recomiendo mires su documentación

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio